# Horizontal Scrollbar Functioning but Only is visible under certain circumstances

Tags: html, css

I have a table that spans the length of multiple screens (horizontally). I tried using both overflow: auto; and overflow: scroll;. The scrolling technically works, the arrow keys work and if I drag and highlight the text of the table going to the right the table scrolls (the scrollbar shows up while doing both of these), but becomes invisible again if nothing is happening.
I do not believe that the scrollbar is in the wrong location as when I refresh the page it shows correctly briefly and if I use the arrow keys or drag as mentioned above the scrollbar does appear in the right spot.
Is there a different setting to keep horizontal scrollbars visible?

```
<div class="analytics-table-class">
<table class="analytics-content-table">
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th>alkdjslskdfjakdjsfkflkdja</th>
         <th>alkdjslskdfjakdjsfkflkdja</th>
         <th>alkdjslskdfjakdjsfkflkdja</th>
         <th>alkdjslskdfjakdjsfkflkdja</th>
         <th>alkdjslskdfjakdjsfkflkdja</th>
         <th>alkdjslskdfjakdjsfkflkdja</th>
         <th>alkdjslskdfjakdjsfkflkdja</th>
         <th>alkdjslskdfjakdjsfkflkdja</th>
         <th>alkdjslskdfjakdjsfkflkdja</th>
         <th>alkdjslskdfjakdjsfkflkdja</th>
         <th>alkdjslskdfjakdjsfkflkdja</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
</table>
<div>
```

CSS

```
 .analytics-content-table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    margin: 20px 0;
    font-size: 15px;
    min-width: 80%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    table-layout: fixed;
 }
 .analytics-table-class{
        width:100vw; 
        overflow: scroll;

    }

 .analytics-content-table thead tr {
    background-color: green;
    color: white;
    text-align: left;
    font-weight: bold;
 }
 .analytics-content-table th,
 .analytics-content-table td {
    padding: 12px 15px;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
 }
```

Code has been simplied/sensitive info removed (why the nonsensical parts)

EDIT:
It seems to be a chrome problem. It runs correctly in edge and as someone commented it works in codepen. Still looking for a fix for chrome if possible.

Comment: ```overflow: scroll;``` should keep scrollbar visible even if there's no content to scroll through, can you share some code so we can check the problem

Comment: i tried your code on codepen and the scrollbar is there and working just fine

Comment: @18jad It's possible it's something chrome specific but it's definitely a problem.

Comment: @18jad yeah it works on edge so it's definitely something to do with chrome. Would that make it unsolvable for the browser or would there be a different way of dealing with it?

Comment: Are you on a Mac by chance? There is a setting at System Preferences > General > Show scroll bars that could be causing this. The default on Macs is that scroll bars only show up while scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

When I look at this in a few different browsers, there is a horizontal scrollbar at the bottom of the page. What you might be experiencing is some kind of interaction between the two.

The scrollbar at the bottom of the page is caused because your main div is using 100% of the view port, but for some browsers, the html or body might have margins and padding making it so that those few pixels at the edges get pushed out of the viewport.

Try adding this to your css:

```
html, body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```